# How to fix commands not working with Discord Bot, hosted through Heroku

Tags: python, github, heroku, bots, discord.py

I have a bot hosted using Heroku, through GitHub. It is online but none of the commands work.

I have no clue what to do, I am not very experienced at this bot hosting thing. The dyno is online and token is in a config variable. Below are requirements.txt and bot.py.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import has_any_role
from discord.ext.commands import CheckFailure
import asyncio
import random
import requests
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")
client.remove_command("help")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_any_role("Postal Manager", "Board of Directors", "Chief Executive Officer")
async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
    user = ctx.message.author
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
    await client.say(f"The role '{role}' has been given to {member.mention} by {user.mention}.")

@giverole.error
async def giverole_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await client.say("Error: Do not have sufficient roles for command.")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_any_role("Postal Manager", "Board of Directors", "Chief Executive Officer")
async def removerole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
    user = ctx.message.author
    await client.remove_roles(member, role)
    await client.say(f"The role '{role}' has been removed from {member.mention} by {user.mention}.")

@removerole.error
async def removerole_error(error,ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await client.say("Error: Do not have sufficient roles for command.")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def allies(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await client.say(f"__**Allies**__ {author.mention} \n \n Our current allies are: \n \n• **DHL** \n \n    DHL is a company that ensures a safe and reliable delivery service. \n\n    **Contract:** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M7y2dpwnItQ2545DlgWEBH9qJRT_0fN3ePGKFCA4Guw/edit?usp=drivesdk \n \n   **Discord:** https://discord.gg/yTEVtPQ")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

bot_token:client.run(str(os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')))
```

```
discord
requests
asyncio
```

Hopefully, when I deploy, the bot will stay online and the commands will work. Many thanks.

Comment: First of all you should upgrade to the newest version of DiscordPy, it will be much easier to read documentation (since it's up to date) and get help.
Second, what's with the last line? Shouldn't it just be `client.run(str(os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')))`

Comment: Let me try that. How do I update discordpy? Edit: Still doesn't work.